# Need help to find the issue in query and optimize it

Tags: sql, database, db2

Using the below query in `DB2` to fetch the records. If no record is found then trying to have default value in that column. But things are not working as expected. There's definitely some issue with query and also need to optimize it. Expecting some help/suggestions/ positive criticism.

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col1),t1.col2,t1.col3,t1.col4,t1.col5
CASE 
WHEN t1.col1 = '' THEN ‘AA99’ ELSE t1.col1 END AS col1
WHEN t1.col2 = '' THEN ‘AA99’ ELSE t1.col2 END AS col2
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
ON (t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 AND t1.col3 = t2.col3 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 t3
ON (t1.col2 = t3.col2)
INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4
ON (t1.col1 = t4.col1 AND t1.col3 = t4.col3)
WHERE (((t1.col1 <> 'NA' OR t1.col1 IS NOT NULL) AND (t2.col1 <> 'NA' OR t2.col1 IS NOT NULL)) 
AND ((t1.col2 <> 'NA' OR t1.col2 IS NOT NULL) AND (t2.col2 <> 'NA' OR t2.col2 IS NOT NULL))
GROUP BY t1.col1,t1.col2 ;
```

Error:

```
1) [Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "WHEN" was found following ".col1
CASE 
".  Expected tokens may include:  "INTO".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.22.29
2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-104", SQLSTATE "42601" and message tokens "WHEN|.col1
CASE 
|INTO".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.22.29
3) Group By is also not working
```

Update_1:

As suggested tried the below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (t1.col1),t1.col2,t1.col3,t1.col4,t1.col5,
CASE 
    WHEN t1.col1 = '' THEN ‘AA99’
    ELSE t1.col1
END AS newcol1,
CASE
    WHEN t1.col2 = '' THEN ‘AA99’
    ELSE t1.col2
END AS newcol2
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
ON (t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 AND t1.col3 = t2.col3 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 t3
ON (t1.col2 = t3.col2)
INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4
ON (t1.col1 = t4.col1 AND t1.col3 = t4.col3)
WHERE (((t1.col1 <> 'NA' OR t1.col1 IS NOT NULL) AND (t2.col1 <> 'NA' OR t2.col1 IS NOT NULL)) 
AND ((t1.col2 <> 'NA' OR t1.col2 IS NOT NULL) AND (t2.col2 <> 'NA' OR t2.col2 IS NOT NULL))
GROUP BY newcol1,newcol2;
```

Error:

```
1) [Code: -206, SQL State: 42703]  "newcol1" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.22.29
2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-206", SQLSTATE "42703" and message tokens "newcol1".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.22.29
```

Its embarrassing but not getting what silly thing I am doing here.

Comment: The third and fourth lines are pretty much duplicates of each other.  Not clear what you actually intend.

Comment: Missing comma after your first CASE for col1?

Comment: DB2 will not like the `‘` character, you will need to use `'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `CASE` part of your second case-when statement. Also, you are selecting col1 and col2, then selecting them again with your case-when statement using an alias, which could explain the group by issues.  Try this version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
t1.col1,
t1.col2,
t1.col3,
t1.col4,
t1.col5,
CASE 
    WHEN t1.col1 = '' THEN ‘AA99’
    ELSE t1.col1
END AS column1,
CASE
    WHEN t1.col2 = '' THEN ‘AA99’
    ELSE t1.col2
END AS column2
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
ON (t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 AND t1.col3 = t2.col3 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 t3
ON (t1.col2 = t3.col2)
INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4
ON (t1.col1 = t4.col1 AND t1.col3 = t4.col3)
WHERE (((t1.col1 <> 'NA' OR t1.col1 IS NOT NULL) AND (t2.col1 <> 'NA' OR t2.col1 IS NOT NULL)) 
AND ((t1.col2 <> 'NA' OR t1.col2 IS NOT NULL) AND (t2.col2 <> 'NA' OR t2.col2 IS NOT NULL))
GROUP BY column1,column2 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use IBM Data Studio, it will highlight where your syntax error starts. That makes it much easier to write syntactically correct SQL such as this

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,t1.col4,t1.col5
,       CASE WHEN t1.col1 = '' THEN 'AA99' ELSE t1.col1 END AS col1
,       CASE WHEN t1.col2 = '' THEN 'AA99' ELSE t1.col2 END AS col2
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
ON (t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 AND t1.col3 = t2.col3)
INNER JOIN TABLE3 t3
ON (t1.col2 = t3.col2)
INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4
ON (t1.col1 = t4.col1 AND t1.col3 = t4.col3)
WHERE ((t1.col1 <> 'NA' OR t1.col1 IS NOT NULL) AND (t2.col1 <> 'NA' OR t2.col1 IS NOT NULL)) 
AND   ((t1.col2 <> 'NA' OR t1.col2 IS NOT NULL) AND (t2.col2 <> 'NA' OR t2.col2 IS NOT NULL))
GROUP BY t1.col1,t1.col2 ;
```

Comment: BTW what kind of optimization are you looking for? I can tell you that you don't need the ` IS NOT NULL` clauses as you are INNER joining on those columns and `NULL` does not match with any value on an INNER JOIN.  Also your GROUP BY won't work - either you are missing columns, or you need to MAX(), MIN() or whatever on the columns not in the CROUP BY.  Also your DISTINCT is redundant, and your CASE statements are identical...  And if this is a "real" query on a "real" database, your column and table names are _really_ very poor!